# How to use ngResource with ngtable select box filtering

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngtable with the custom filtering. I am bringing in my data with resource. I am trying to get it to work with one ajax call. I did get it working when I made a call for the table and for each select box. this however is not efficient. I have switched the var data to $scope.data as suggested by other solutions. It is not working.

```
 var data = {};
$scope.data = DocumentUser.query();
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    counts: [], // hide page counts control
    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
      //  DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                    $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                    $scope.data;
            orderedData = params.filter ?
                    $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) :
                    orderedData;

            $scope.data = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

            params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
       // });
    }
});

var inArray = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
        function (val, arr) {
            return arr.indexOf(val)
        } :
        function (val, arr) {
            var i = arr.length;
            while (i--) {
                if (arr[i] === val) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
$scope.DocumentTypes = function (column) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        DocumentTypes = [];
   // DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item) {
            if (inArray(item.DocumentType, arr) === -1) {
                arr.push(item.DocumentType);
                DocumentTypes.push({
                    'id': item.DocumentType,
                    'title': item.DocumentType
                });
            }
       // });
    });
    def.resolve(DocumentTypes);
    return def;
};//
$scope.DocumentLocations = function (column) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        DocumentLocations = [];
   // DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item) {
            if (inArray(item.DocumentLocation, arr) === -1) {
                arr.push(item.DocumentLocation);
                DocumentLocations.push({
                    'id': item.DocumentLocation,
                    'title': item.DocumentLocation
                });
            }
        //});
    });
    def.resolve(DocumentLocations);
    return def;
};//
$scope.DocumentPlants = function (column) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        DocumentPlants = [];
   // DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item) {
            if (inArray(item.DocumentPlant, arr) === -1) {
                arr.push(item.DocumentPlant);
                DocumentPlants.push({
                    'id': item.DocumentPlant,
                    'title': item.DocumentPlant
                });
            }
        //});
    });
    def.resolve(DocumentPlants);
    return def;
};
```

Update

```
 $scope.data = {};
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    counts: [], // hide page counts control
    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        //  DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
        // use build-in angular filter
        var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                $scope.data;
        orderedData = params.filter ?
                $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) :
                orderedData;

        $scope.data = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

        params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
        $defer.resolve($scope.data);
    }
});

$scope.data = DocumentUser.query({}, function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngResource immediately returns an object. For query it is actually an empty array with a promise attached ($promise). Your `getData` function is building the table with an empty array. There are many ways to solve this, but one simple thing is just to call reload on the table params (which will cause another call to `getData()`). You can just do that when the promise finishes.

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    counts: [], // hide page counts control
    total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
      //  DocumentUser.query(function (data) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                    $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                    $scope.data;
            orderedData = params.filter ?
                    $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) :
                    orderedData;

            orderedData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

            params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
            $defer.resolve(orderedData);
        });
    }
    $scope.data = DocumentUser.query({}, function(){
         $scope.tableParams.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: i posted exactly what i have. nothing is coming up

Comment: I am seeing this in the console [$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]

Comment: I edited my answer. Didn't see that you were overwriting $scope.data. Again, this is not the only solution, but you need to understand promises and the way getData works before you will be able to get this working smoothly.